# AndEngine: Not running on ICS 4.0.3 r2 emulator

Tags: android, emulation, opengl-es-2.0, andengine

I was reading [this post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/04/faster-emulator-with-better-hardware.html). Google says that your OpenGL ES 2.0 games can now run inside the emulator. I got the ICS 4.0.3 r2 and created an emulator with gpu emulation enabled but it gives again the same error that 'No EGLConfig found!'. I am using 32 bit windows 7. Is there any other things to do to make it work?

Comment: AFAIK OpenGL ES 2.0 does not work with Google provided ARM images - but Intel Atom images do support OpenGL ES 2.0 too.

Comment: OpenGLES 2.0 works fine with google ICS emulator for me. @harism

Comment: @Tim is this on Windows? I'm using OSX and I'm facing issues when I try setting context client version to 2.

Comment: Yes, windows in my case.

Comment: Ah I got it to work on OSX too now that I tried it second time today. Maybe GPU emulation flag wasn't checked when I created a JB emulator earlier today.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but some information about this issue I found only in russian blog by http://moregamedev.blogspot.com/2012/04/4-andengine-gles2-examples-intellij.html